# is there way to hide the start of a light and only show it after it touches an object?

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

I am doing a render in blender and I wanted to add a dusty old feel to a scene so I added volumetrics but as soon as i added it you could see the source of the lights inside and it looks really bad. Is there a way to only show the light when its touching the object i want it to touch?
[image]

Comment: you can make other lights invisible to volume scatter. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189589/how-to-create-volume-scattering-material-not-throwing-shadow/189593?noredirect=1#comment317458_189593

Comment: It doesnt seem that you are able to do that in the version 2.8 that I failed to mention in the start question. Ray visibility does not exist at least were it is located in that question. Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: It does in cycles, please specify what render engine you are using.

Comment: would you think there is a way to do it in evee?